# HTTP 500 (Backend Error) for GET /videos with certain ids

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Seeking support of Google engineers since this is clearly a persistent YouTube API bug.

I was searching for videos using YouTube v3 API, and "p2hcYliOqic" video ID was returned among other IDs. Supplying it to /videos endpoint consistently leads to HTTP 500 with "Backend Error" message. This is just an example, the problem is wider (I can find more ids causing that issue). Here's an example of request (API key replaced with MY_API_KEY):

```
curl -X GET -H "content-length: 0" -H "host: www.googleapis.com" "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=p2hcYliOqic&part=snippet&key=MY_API_KEY"
```

Response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

Supplying this ID among other ids leads to same result, HTTP 500, and that is a serious issue. I'd like YouTube API to ignore video IDs it can't handle and not fail the request completely. If user supplies a non-existent video ID, YouTube API v3 just returns an empty result (or non-empty result in case there's at least one real & "non-buggy" ID) — I wish the same happen for "problematic" IDs.

Comment: If this is a bug report for the YouTube API, StackOverflow isn't the place to report it. To report it you should take a look at the [report form](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report))

Comment: Thanks, will do as well. However, YouTube API docs, Support section, claims that support is performed on StackOverflow, by monitoring of tags "youtube-api youtube-data-api youtube-v3-api" by Google support team.

Comment: You are correct in that they like to use SO for technical questions and support, they are careful to state that SO is not the place for Bug Reports or Feature requests. "We recommend that developers use 'Stack Overflow' for technical API questions, and the Issue Tracker templates for reporting a bug and filing a feature request"

Comment: Hmm, [lin]https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support[/link] says that:

```How to Get Help

We support the YouTube Data API on Stack Overflow. Google engineers monitor and answer questions with the youtube-api, youtube-data-api, and youtube-v3-api tags.
```

Comment: My apologies if this question annoys some of you, guys. For the moment I'm keeping it open to help other people having the same issue with requests to YouTube API. When something isn't working, making it work is a technical question, right? A question people needs to solve whether or not YouTube resolves their issue.

Comment: This is kind of ridiculous. We have the exact same issue and this issue is two years old. The official solution google wants you to implement is documented here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#500_backend_error "Exponential backoff" is really just a fancy way to say "retry task in ever increasing intervals". I think it's a bit of a shame that a company like google hasn't come up with a better solution than this but it seems like this is what we've got for now...

Answer (score 1):

For those facing similar YouTube symptoms (i.e. a GET request to /videos with 100 video ids which just fails with "Backend Error" for no particular reason) there's a detour. In your code you need to add a handler that will break such requests into smaller ones and send them until all non-buggy IDs go through. I split to 3 queries in this case. E.g. if 100-vid request fails (because of "Backend Error", not quota issue or something else specifically noted in API response), I break it to 34-vid, 33-vid, 33-vid. If there's only one buggy ID, only one of these requests will fail, and after that I split it to 3 parts again. This way all non-buggy IDs go through, but this approach is costlier to your YouTube requests quota (if requests fail).